# Manipulate XSLT file in C#

Tags: c#, xslt, xpath

I've a program using XSLT file to generate PDF files, somme nodes in the XSLT file have an attribute `font-family`.
We want make the font configuarable in the config file, which means that we want modify the value of all attributes before the applying the xslt style :

```
public void GeneratePDF(string xsltPath, DataSet data)
{
  XslCompiledTransform xslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();

  // here I want modify all elements having the font-family attribute
   xslTrans.Load(path)
   //....
}
```

The XSLT file looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

  <xsl:import href="../masterLayout.xslt" />
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:param name="ServerAppPath" select="'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\webApi'"/>
  <xsl:param name="Orientation" select="'Portrait'"/>
  <xsl:param name="PaperSize" select="'A4'"/>   
  <xsl:template match="StatusA">
        <fo:root>
            <xsl:call-template name="FOFileHeader"/>

            <!-- DOCUMENT -->
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="pages" font-family="Verdana" initial-page-number="1" font-size="8pt">
                <xsl:call-template name="Region1"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="Region2"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="FirstRegionAfter"/>
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" font-size="8pt">
```

Comment: Have you tried using one of [the overloads of the Load method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.load?view=netframework-4.7.2) which allows you to load an XSLT stylesheet?

Comment: No, Ididn't, Do you mean  Load(XmlReader stylesheet) ? load the XSLT via xml reader then update the attribute ?

Comment: Well, XSLT is XML and XSLT is a transformation language to transform XML so you can for sure use XSLT to transform some other XSLT into a third XSLT. On the other hand, depending on your needs it suffices to declare global parameters with e.g. `<xsl:param name="font-family">Arial</xsl:param>` which you can then reference elsewhere in your code with e.g. `<fo:block font-family="{$font-family}">...</fo:block>` and then with your .NET API you pass in an `XsltArgumentList` to the `Transform` method.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, thank you for your answer, I'm new in XSLT and I don't know how can I acheive this to get a third xslt, iIcan not declare a parameter because some xslt are saved in db and they depend on the client (i'ven't access to the client dbs).

Comment: Can your edit your question to show a sample of the XSLT. Not necessarily the whole XSLT, but the bit where `font-family` is currently set (i.e the bit you want to change). Thanks!

Comment: I've added an example of font, but as i said, the xslt could be customized by the clients

Comment: Thanks. The XSLT you have posted confirms that Martin's answer is almost certainly the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT is XML and therefore you can use XSLT to transform one XSLT stylesheet into another, a simple example is

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:param name="font-family">Times New Roman</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="font-size">16pt</xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="fo:*/@font-family">
      <xsl:attribute name="font-family">
          <xsl:value-of select="$font-family"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="fo:*/@font-size">
      <xsl:attribute name="font-size">
          <xsl:value-of select="$font-size"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which as its input expects any XML or XSLT document containing some XSL-FO elements with `font-family` or `font-size` attributes and transforms these to take the value from the global parameters.

An online example is https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTAo

In the .NET API you can use `XsltArgumentList` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xsl.xsltargumentlist?view=netframework-4.7.2) to set such global parameters when running an XSLT with the `Transform` method (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.transform?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add another parameter to the stylesheet?

```
 <xsl:param name="FontFamilty" select="'Verdana'"/>
```

...

```
 <fo:page-sequence master-reference="pages" font-family="{$FontFamily}"...
```